# What is the callback function when app unlock from lock screen to my app screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, lockscreen, viewwillappear

I thought it was viewWillAppear function, but it did not.

Is not exist unlock callback function in iOS?

Comment: You mean: open your app, lock screen, and unlock, this time your app appears, and what function is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods called when locking the device with your app currently in foreground are in order

```
-[MyAppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:]
-[MyAppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:]
-[MyAppDelegate applicationWillEnterForeground:]
-[MyAppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:]
```

The first two are called when locking, the others when unlocking

Comment: Thank you. Solved the problem.